# Div has no effect on outcome, doesnt read border and other similar properties, can't postion, when commented out has effect on included elements

Tags: html, css

I have removed irrelevant stuff to keep the question short, I had an issue with the same code earlier, I asked few more questions after it was resolved but did not hear back, that's why make a new post.

maintext class is not responding to any CSS styling e.g. border, background or other cosmetic properties, but has a major effect on the enclosing elements when commented out or deleted. Even an empty CSS declaration keeps the contents together when maintext class is deleted/commented out h1 spreads out and the effects go wild.

I want to position the maintext class including content elements to the right middle of the landing page. I can position button element and h1 items separately using with maintext class, using left and top properties, but I want the maintext block to position as a single unit.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&family=Reggae+One&display=swap');
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(main.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

html::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: -10;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 52%;
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
}

.menu ul {
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(main.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-x: -650px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: tranparent .6;
}

.menu ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu ul li {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* padding: 7px 15px; */
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  position: static;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background: transparent;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  color: red;
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 200px 200px rgba(92,137,204,.3); */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 200px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3); */
  background: transparent;
}


/* /* .am
           {
                   position:absolute;
           }
    
    
           ul.am{
                   position: absolute;
                   /* border: 2px solid red; */


/* list-style-type:none;
                   list-style-position: inside;
                   text-decoration: none;
                   display:none;
                    */

*/
/* }
           ul.am li{
                   display:block;
                   text-align: left;
                   margin-left:-40px;
                   padding:5px 0;
                   }
    
    
                   .menu ul li:hover ul.am{
                           display:block;
                   } */

*/
/*Main text on the main page*/

.maintext {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.maintext h1 {
  z-index: 23;
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 900px;
  top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: -10px;
  animation: show .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.maintext h1 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  animation: overlay 1s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(1) span {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(2) span {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

h1:nth-of-type(3) span {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.maintext .butt {
  z-index: 45;
  position: relative;
  left: 900px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.maintext .butt:hover {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 200px 200px rgba(92, 137, 204, .3);
  background: transparent;
}

.maintext .align h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes overlay {
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  100% {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .8);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></samp>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="maintext">
    <h1 class="align">Hello, <span></span></h1><br>
    <h1 class="align">My Name is <span></span></h1><br>
    <h1 class="align">Abc Xyz <span></span></h1><br>

    <!-- <button class="butt align">Portfolio</button> -->
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: You didn't give it `.maintext` a width and height. Of course it appears nothing is happening because it has no size. give it width and height and you'll see the element.

Comment: hi @Justin, I thought so too, I did give it a  height and width but nothing happened..

Comment: Interesting because I copied you code to Codepen and did that and it showed right up.

Comment: here I also changed the border width to 10 to make sure you see it https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/mdWJKMX?editors=1100

Comment: I copied word to work from visual studio code to here, I can see the border is showing with height and width in codepen, but if you have only entered height and width to it, then there is something wrong on my PC, cause I re-checked, border is still not showing up after entering height and width to .maintext..

Comment: Must be something with your PC. I just copied and pasted into VSCode along with `portfolio.css` and it loaded right up. I added width and height and its working. I also change the border color to black to see it better.  ```.maintext{
             z-index: 10000;   
             width: 200px;
             height: 200px;       
             border: 2px solid black; 
              padding:0;
           margin:0;   
    }```

Comment: I see its working flawlessly on codepen, I am not sure whats wrong with the PC cause every other styling is working fine.

Comment: All I can say is start commenting out sections piece by piece until you find what's causing it. I loaded it through VSCode in both Firefox and Edge and it shows fine. You may have more code in you actual file than what you posted here.

Comment: Hey Justin, I have just copy pasted the complete code from VS to SO,  border around the maintext is not showing at all, neither any styling done in it is taking effect..

Comment: That section above `.maintext` that has all the extra close comments `*/` is causing you issues. Delete all the extra `*/` or delete that whole section and it will show. I'm referring to the section that is commented out just above `.maintext`

Comment: that was it, they were two of them.. thank you for spending time on this.. now the .menutext is working as it should.. thanks a ton

Comment: no problem, glad it's working.